# Vanilla tree-sitter setup not enables highlighting automatically

Tags: neovim, plugin-treesitter, lazyvim

I am failing to configure [`nvim-treesitter`](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) to automatically highlight the code upon opening a file.

After configuring `nvim-treesitter` by following the [recommended instruction steps](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/wiki/Installation#lazynvim), this is what I get:

[image]

- running `:TSInstallInfo` reveals that Elixir parser **is not installed**:

  ```
  elixir           [✗] not installed
  ```
- running `:TSModuleInfo` reveals that for Elixir language, **all modules are disabled**:

  ```
          highlight  incremental_selection  indent
          ...        ...                    ...
  elixir  ✗          ✗                      ✗
          ...        ...                    ...
  ```

Should I "instruct" `nvim-treesitter` to install the parser using `:TSInstall elixir` and then manually enable the highlighting inside the desired buffer using `:TSBufToggle highlight` - the code appears to be colorised correctly:

[image]

**What whould I change about my config to make `nvim-treesitter` install and enabled highlighting (and `incremental selection` and `indent` modules, for that matter) automatically?**

I wasn't sure if should open a GitHub issue for this, and if so - to which project, e.g. `nvim-treesitter` or [`lazy.nvim`](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim), the package manager I am using. Hence posting my question here.

For the purpose of preparing a minimal reproduction example, I've isolated `neovim`'s config directory, as well as its data directory into the following folder structure:

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── data
├── elixir-code-sample.exs
└── nvim
    ├── init.lua
    └── lazy-lock.json
$
```

Here's my `init.lua` in its entirety:

```lua
print("Issue with tree-sitter configuration")

-- 1. bootstrap lazy.nvim
--
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-- 2. install tree-sitter.nvim plugin
--
require("lazy").setup({{"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter", build = ":TSUpdate"}})

-- 3. make things on a screen a little nicer
--
vim.cmd.colorscheme("evening")
vim.opt.termguicolors = true
```

Here's how I run `neovim` while in the root of a folder tree, displated above:

```shell
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$(realpath .) XDG_DATA_HOME=$(realpath data) nvim elixir-sample.exs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now. Had to make the following change to a config above:

```
 -- 2. install tree-sitter.nvim plugin
 --
-require("lazy").setup({{"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter", build = ":TSUpdate"}})
+require("lazy").setup({
+  {'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter',
+    build = ":TSUpdate",
+    config = function()
+      local configs = require 'nvim-treesitter.configs'
+      configs.setup {
+        ensure_installed = {
+          'elixir',
+        },
+        highlight = {
+          enable = true
+        },
+      }
+    end,
+  }
+})

 -- 3. make things on a screen a little nicer
 --
```